# Find the content and increment value from Ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have json file which contains following peace of lines.
I need to find and increment the last number "1.39.25.1" like 1.39.25.2, 1.39.25.3 so on by a ruby code.

```
    "appVersion": {
    "buildFlavour": "varation",
    "customisation": "MY.VER.NUM",
    "version": "1.39.25.1"
},
```

Please help on this

Comment: This kind of questions is an offtopic here. SO **is not** a service where people write code for you for free.

Comment: You don't need to write code for me. simply give the hint that's it!. else skip it

Answer (score 1):

String#succ is a quick and easy way:

```
"1.39.25.1".succ  #=> "1.39.25.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*others, last = "1.39.25.1".split(".")
[*others, last.next].join(".")
# => "1.39.25.2"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. will check and confirm you.